Is Kant's dislike of servility related to his formula of humanity?

Kant tells us that acting in a servile fashion or disavowing one's
dignity constitute failures to properly value oneself
https://philarchive.org/archive/STATRO-20/1000

Which makes sense but Ive never seen servility specifically mentioned in relation to the FH, so Im wondering if its implied that Kant means servility is the agent treating themselves as a means?

“Now, I say, man and, in general, every rational being exists as an end in himself and not merely as a means to be arbitrarily used by this or that will.  In all his actions, whether they are directed to himself or to other rational beings, he must always be regarded at the same time as an end . . .” Kant

I argue here the motivating principle of Kant's moral reasoning, the Categorical Imperative, is intersubjectivity: Is the Categorical Imperative Simply Bad Math? :)
That is, being in community with like-minded others. Slavery, serfdom, feudalism, rely on manufacturing servility by some, and a fundamental difference between groups. That wastes talents, by the people not valuing themselves being the refle tion of society not valuing them as individuals but only as categories.

When Kant writes “Now, I say, man and, in general, every rational being exists as an end in himself and not merely as a means to be arbitrarily used by this or that will. In all his actions, whether they are directed to himself or to other rational beings, he must always be regarded at the same time as an end . . .” (as quoted by @ChrisDegnen), what is the "must" here? Is it a moral command? Is it a necessary truth required to assume for any moral system?

And what actually does "end in itself" mean (why for instance is it reserved for so-called 'rational' beings, why not for all living beings, or even for any empirical object)? What are the actual implications of this? (For instance, it seems to imply that suicide is immoral. Or does it not?)

(Btw - These questions are just an aside - not related to the OPs question - so perhaps best ignored here.)
